# Ring automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory

Looking for some clarification of my work. The basis elements of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{5}]$ are $\{1,\sqrt[3]{5}, (\sqrt[3]{5})^2\}$. It's a ring homomorphism thus we have ${1}\rightarrow{1}$ and the automorphism is the image of $\sqrt[3]{5}$.

$\phi(\mathbb{\sqrt[3]{5}})^3=5.$$\;$ Let $x=\phi(\mathbb{\sqrt[3]{5}})$ and we have: $$x^3-5=x^3-(\mathbb{\sqrt[3]{5}})^3=(\mathbb{\sqrt[3]{5}})^3\left(\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{5}}\right)^3-1\right)=(\sqrt[3]{5})^3\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{5}}-1\right)\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{5}}-\omega\right)\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{5}}-\omega^2\right)=(\sqrt[3]{5})^3(x-\sqrt[3]{5})(x-\omega\sqrt[3]{5})(x-\omega^2\sqrt[3]{5})$$

Thus the zeros are: $$\sqrt[3]{5}, \sqrt[3]{5}\:\omega, \sqrt[3]{5}\:\omega^2,$$
where $$\omega=\frac{(-1+\sqrt{-3})}{2}.$$

As two of the zeros are complex numbers they are not elements of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{5}]$ and the automorphism is the map $\sqrt[3]{5}\rightarrow\sqrt[3]{5}$. Correct?

Comment: The basis elements of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{5}]$ are $\{1,\sqrt[3]{5},\sqrt[3]{5}^2\}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{\sqrt[3]{5}}$ is something I do not see very often at MSE. Looks interesting!

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is practically the same case as with $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)\;$, which appears much more.

Comment: @DonAntonio I mean the Bourbaki font, not the mathematics (it needs magnifying glasses, perhaps).

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning and conclusion are correct:
the identity is the only automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{5}]$.